# How to add a progress bar in CefSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wanted to know how to add a progress bar to a small download window to my current download handler. Currently my browser just downloads the file without any notice to the user or any finished warning. So, what can I do to add a browser progress bar. If you want any more detail you can always add a comment and I will try to provide it.

Regrads Adit

```
using CefSharp;
using System;

namespace new_browser
{
    class MyCustomDownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
    {
        public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnBeforeDownloadFired;

        public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnDownloadUpdatedFired;

        public bool CanDownload(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string url, string requestMethod)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void OnBeforeDownload(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
        {
            if (downloadItem.IsValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("== File information ========================");
                Console.WriteLine(" File URL: {0}", downloadItem.Url);
                Console.WriteLine(" Suggested FileName: {0}", downloadItem.SuggestedFileName);
                Console.WriteLine(" MimeType: {0}", downloadItem.MimeType);
                Console.WriteLine(" Content Disposition: {0}", downloadItem.ContentDisposition);
                Console.WriteLine(" Total Size: {0}", downloadItem.TotalBytes);
                Console.WriteLine("============================================");
            }

            OnBeforeDownloadFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);

            if (!callback.IsDisposed)
            {
                using (callback)
                {
                    callback.Continue(
                        downloadItem.SuggestedFileName,
                        showDialog: true
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        /// https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_DownloadItem.htm
        public void OnDownloadUpdated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
        {
            OnDownloadUpdatedFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);

            if (downloadItem.IsValid)
            {
                // Show progress of the download
                if (downloadItem.IsInProgress && (downloadItem.PercentComplete != 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Current Download Speed: {0} bytes ({1}%)",
                        downloadItem.CurrentSpeed,
                        downloadItem.PercentComplete
                    );
                }

                if (downloadItem.IsComplete)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The download has been finished !");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler way is to use the progressbar control, you can update the value of the control in OnDownloadUpdated.

Demo:

```
if (downloadItem.IsValid)
    {
        if (downloadItem.IsInProgress && (downloadItem.PercentComplete != 0))
        {
            progressBar.Value = downloadItem.PercentComplete;
        }

        if (downloadItem.IsComplete)
        {
            progressBar.Value = 100;
        }
    }
```

Refer to the [progressbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) document for details, and you may need to add corresponding references.

Comment: if (downloadItem.IsInProgress && (downloadItem.PercentComplete != 0))
                {
                    _form.progressBar1.Value = downloadItem.PercentComplete;
                    
                }

                if (downloadItem.IsComplete)
                {
                    _form.progressBar1.Value = downloadItem.PercentComplete;
                }